# Firebird - using before insert trigger for a master table to sum detail records

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, firebird

I have two tables a master and detail. the detail table records are created automatically using a trigger **after** insert new master record.

But I need to create `Before Insert or Update` trigger (call it `T1`) for the master table to do some calculations based on fields from master record and sum from its detail records.

My problem to be able to do my calculations in `T1` I need to insert details records first but of course the detail records has foreign key constraint to the master table ID which prevent this action so what do you think the best approach to achieve this task ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the best approach is to use a stored procedure that does all the work... 
something like this:

```
create procedure insert_record(id integer, ...);
as
begin
    /* this inserts master and through triggers creates detail */
    insert into master (id, ... ) 
    values (:id, ...);

    /* calculate values */
    select sum(...) from detail
    where id = :id
    into :calculation;

    /* usa calculated value to update master table */
    update master
    set calculated_value = :calculation
    here id = :id;
end
```

Comment: This SP will afire `After Insert or Update` for the master table ?

Comment: @Welliam I think he suggests to use a stored procedure to do all the work instead of using triggers.

Comment: However I drooped the constraint and made automatic delete done from a trigger.